# What do you call a non-technical database

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The German term "Datenbasis" (un- or processed data resource) could be simply translated into database, as Langenscheidt shows [Link to Langenscheidt's Translation](http://de.langenscheidt.com/deutsch-englisch/datenbasis?term=Datenbasis&q_cat=%2Fdeutsch-englisch%2F). But imagine, when you write about something pretty scientific, you would perhaps gather data which needs not to be in digital form, but could be results of measurements done manually and written down on paper.

So what is the term for a collection of such data that has *not* been deposited in a database of a computerized database management system such as *Oracle*, *MySQL* etc?

Comment: I think you just want data. Or maybe a study?

Comment: Or maybe *dataset*.

Comment: Well, thank you all for your suggestions. I am still unsure. It seems the english language does not distinguish the word data in other synonyms than records, which can be either from database or manually written down data. In the german language this is somehow in a peculiar and subtle way possible due to composite words on the fly. It's a pity, that we humans have such a few words to describe the quality of information, respectively giving a hint of its origin in an all-inclusive word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, my liege. I edited the question.

Comment: @Semo "_It seems the English language does not distinguish ... In the German language ... possibly due to composite words on the fly_" I don't speak German, but from what I know of it, English can be just as expressive; the main difference being you _joinAllYourSubtlyNuancedWordsOnTheFly_ into one whereas we _keep separate all the expressions of fine-tuned gradations in meaning_. :-)

Comment: As you did not make the correction @Mari-Lou suggested I have done it for you and  clarified your second para choosing expressions that do not prejudice or invalidate answers. However I would also like to change your title as it begs the question (incorrectly in my opinion). I think "What do you call a collection of unprocessed data" better represents what you are asking. You seem to be misusing technical to mean unprocessed as further in your question you refer to scientific data (self-evidently technical) recorded on paper.

Comment: Two other options are *compendium* and, if organized on a yearly basis, *almanac*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You said, the question's title is wrong english and suggested to correct it. But which error do you mean? Unfortunately I can't find a copy of my original question.
To the downvoters: Why the downvoting?

Comment: Look at the edit history. This is easer if you are on a desktop computer. I think tbe SE mobile site makes this virtually impossible to see. The words "How do you call....?" were on the last paragraph. I upvoted your question by the way.

Comment: David, thanks for the improved 2nd paragraph. It is indeed better, than before. I just didn't want to be too formal. @Mari-LouA Worked. Thanks. I wonder, so much toil for a simple term. :-D :-D So now I don't know again which of the answers might be the best. Unfortunately I can't leastwise upvote their answers. But I can write: Have a great day, everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the word `data` is more appropriate here:

```
Data: facts and statistics collected together for reference or analysis.
```

`Data set` seems more like a term from the computer science.

Comment: This is what I would think, but have you got a reference to this assumption, which I would read?

Comment: @Semo For example here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dataset

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember from books on mathematical statistics, they call it often simply "data sets". If we mention "data" it is not implicitly assumed that the collected data has some common origin or are bound together by a common source like measured results of experiments. We may try in a sentence like: In the next step we loaded the measured data sets into our database.

Answer (score 1):

Such *manual* "databases" were typically maintained in notebooks or otherwise bound sheets (in file folders, for example) and called ***logs/records***.

ODO:

> **[record](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/record)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** A thing constituting a piece of evidence about the past, especially an account kept in writing or some other permanent form:
>
> ‘a record of meter readings’
>
> **[log](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/log)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **2.1** A regular or systematic record of incidents or observations:
>
> ‘keep a detailed log of your activities’

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the entry for [Datenbasis in Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datenbasis) — and your description in English — what you are referring to would be termed:

> ***raw* data**

as in one of the examples for [‘raw’ in Oxford Dictionary on Line](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/raw):

> 1.2 (of data) not analysed, evaluated, or processed for use.
>
> ‘there were a number of errors in the raw data’

or, perhaps

> **a dataset** or **data set**

defined by the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/data_set) as:

> A collection of related sets of information that is composed of
> separate elements but can be manipulated as a unit by a computer.

I believe that your title is incorrect, however, as *Datenbasis* cannot be translated as *database* in English if it means *eine Menge an Daten* (a quantity of data) as the Wikipedia entry states. Neither of the terms *raw data* or *data set* I have suggested are synonymous with database, one feature of which is that the data are organized in some specific manner. Whether it is ‘technical’ or not has nothing to do with it, unless by ‘non-technical’ you mean unprocessed. The English *database* would seem rather to be equivalent to the German *Datenbank*.